# Convergence with probability 1

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Given $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ the sequence $X_n$ is uniformly bounded and $S_{n^2}/n^2 \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1. Show that $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1.

So I was able to prove that $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ (in probability) and I know that $S_{n^2}/n^2 \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1 implies $\lim_n E\left( S_{n^2}/n^2 \right) = 0$, and then I used the Markov’s inequality to bound the probability $P(|S_n| \geq n\epsilon) \leq ES_n/(n\epsilon)$. However, I can’t find a convergent series that larger than $\sum_n P(|S_n| \geq n\epsilon)$.

Remark: Since I didn’t make it clear, here I want to prove that 
$P(|S_n/n| > \epsilon \ i.o.) = 0$.

Comment: If you managed to prove that $S_n/n \to 0$ (presumably with probability 1) as stated at the beginning of the second paragraph, then what is your question?

Comment: I was only able to prove $S_n/n \to 0$ but not with probability 1. I should make it clear.

Comment: Then in what sense did you prove $S_n/n \to 0$? In probability?

Comment: I just added to my question. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markov's inequality alone necessarily fails because it cannot distinguish OP's case from the case where $S_n/n \not\to 0$ with probability one. For instance, consider the example where $X_n = 1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ is uniformly bounded, but $S_n/n \to 1 \neq 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

To establish the desired convergence, for each $n \geq 1$ we denote $a_n = \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$. Then by the triangle inequality,

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right|
\leq \left| \frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{S_{a_n^2}}{n} \right| + \left| \frac{S_{a_n^2}}{n} \right|
= \frac{|S_n - S_{a_n^2}|}{n} + \frac{a_n^2}{n} \left| \frac{S_{a_n^2}}{a_n^2} \right|.
\end{align*}

Now pick a bound $M$of $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$. Then by using the fact that $a_n^2 \leq n \leq a_n^2 + 2\sqrt{n} $, we get

$$|S_n - S_{a_n^2}| \leq \sum_{a_n^2 < k \leq n} |X_k| \leq (n - a_n^2) M \leq 2\sqrt{n}M, $$

and so,

$$ \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| \leq \frac{2 M}{\sqrt{n}} + \left| \frac{S_{a_n^2}}{a_n^2} \right|. $$

Since this upper bound converges to $0$ with probability one, the desired claim follows.

Comment: Ah I see! I kept trying to bound it with known inequalities without thinking about I can just bound it normally.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a property of real sequences. Let $a_n=S_n$. Then $\frac {a_{n^{2}}} {n^{2}} \to 0$ and $(\frac {a_n} n)$ is bounded. There exists $M$ such that $|a_j-a_k| \leq |j-k| M$ and $|a_n| \leq nM$. Let $n^{2} \leq k \leq (n+1)^{2}$. Then $\frac {|a_k|} k \leq \frac {|a_{n^{2}}|+(k-n^{2})M} k  \leq \frac {|a_{n^{2}}|} {n^{2}}+\frac {(k-n^{2})M} k\to 0$. I have used the fact that $\frac {(k-n^{2})} k \leq \frac {2n+1} {n^{2}} \to 0$ as $ k \to \infty$.